# csscomb.js で JavaScript コードの整形ができますか？

Tags: javascript, coding-style

csscomb.jsがJavaScriptのソースコードに対して、うまくいきません。
cssの方はうまくいっています。
csscomb.jsでJavaScriptのフォーマットを行なう方法はありますか？

他の所では回答がなかったので、終了しこちらに変更しました。
okwave.jp/qa/q9347884.html

Comment: マルチポスト　https://okwave.jp/qa/q9347884.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSScomb](https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js) は、

> CSScomb is a coding style formatter for CSS.

という事ですから、JavaScript を整形する機能はありません。

GitHub のプロジェクト名「csscomb.js」の「js」は JavaScript によって実装されている事を示すものです。
CSScomb は最初 PHP による実装から始まったようですので、それと区別することが「js」を付ける第一の目的だと思います。
また、`js`、`go`、`py` など、実装言語を示すキーワードをプロジェクト名に付けることは一般によくあるパターンとなっています。

Comment: https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js
にある物は違うのですか？
下記にもあります
http://www.webdesignleaves.com/wp/htmlcss/788/

Comment: csscomb.jsはjsとあるのにjsを整理するの物ではないのか。＞＞＞エディタなどに仕込まないと意味が無いのではないでしょうか。＞＞＞これがどういった意味合いかよくわかりませんがサブライムならサブライム上のプラグインで行うという事ですか？

Comment: @nicomesecond  「サブライムならサブ‌​ライム上のプラグインで行うという事ですか‌​？」その通りです。（本題とずれるので、回答からはカットしました。疑問が解消しない場合は別の質問になさるのがよいと思います）

Comment: Prettify Codeにしようと思います。一番使われていそうなので